# NSString literal to uint32_t

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm not sure if the title is correct for what I need to do, but I simply need to take a literal `NSString` string and make it a `uint32_t`

Basically this is what I'm wanting to do:

```
NSString *literal = @"0x0001234";
uint32_t = literal; // uint32_t = 0x0001234;
```

I tried using some casts but those just gave me errors, so how can I do this?

*I'm not too familiar with Obj-C, so not sure what I should be searching for exactly.

Comment: @matt: The NSString is the input, and the output would be the string converted into uint32_t, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a simple assignment, even with a case, because `NSString` and `uint32` are completely different things.

You can use the `NSScanner` `scanHexInt` method.  Note that this method can fail if the string isn't a valid hex string.

```
NSString *literal = @"0x0001234";
unsigned output = 0;
if ([[NSScanner scannerWithString:literal] scanHexInt:&output]) {
   // Do something with output
} else {
   // Unable to parse string
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. When I check the result it says `4660` `NSLog(@"%u", output);`. Do I need something else to get `0x0001234`?

Comment: As Matt says, 4660 is 0x1234 - %u outputs decimal.

Comment: @matt: I was hoping for the hex value `0x0001234` to set `uint32_t` actually (`uint32_t hex = 0x0001234;`) so I'll have to convert it?

Comment: Try `%x` instead of `%u` - You will get 0x1234.  The value in `output` is the same.  All that is changing is how you are formatting it when you print it.